# Is there any way to add a source file through a pragma?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-2010

Is there any way, via a pragma directive, to add a source file to the list of files to be compiled in Visual Studio 10?  That way header files could bring their implementation files along with them whenever they are included.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is the situation you're describing a rather odd one? Usually the problem that you describe applies to library files to link, not source files to compile. There is a `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` to add a library file to the list of things a linker can use to resolve references. However, an analogous `#pragma` for source files do not exist, because the IDE passes the paths of all your source files in your project to the compiler for you. I don't quite understand what you aim to achieve with a "compile source pragma".

Comment: @In silico: I would find it more convenient if I didn't have to have a project for my library that I would have to update each time I modified the source file.  That's all I'm asking for, is a convenience.

Comment: Move implementation to header file, making it header-only? Or #include "file.cpp"?

Comment: In visual studio you can define project dependencies and then when you change your lib and run your exe, the lib will automatically get recompiled as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such thing. It would make it awfully complicated to keep track of project dependencies if something like that was supported.

But there is something like that for libraries. Say you have a library called library.lib and a header file that declares the symbols for this library called library.h. You can include the following pragma in library.h:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "library.lib")
```

And then any project that includes library.h will link against library.lib automatically.

This option is described on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7(v=vs.80).aspx) on MSDN.